# Pad single digit numbers in column with leading zero

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a requirement to pad any single digit numbers in a string field with a leading zero. I only need to pad single numeric characters with a leading zero, not string alphabetic characters (A-Z). Below is an example of the current data, along with the expected output for these examples.

```
Current output     Expected output:
9                  09    
19                 19   
15                 15
F                  F
UR                 UR           
B                  B  
0                  00    
4                  04
N                  N
00                 00
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `CASE` expression to check whether the column contains only 0 to 9. If true then prefix with 0 else as it is.

**Query**

```
select 
  case when col like '[0-9]' 
    then '0' + col
  else col end as newcol  
from tablename;
```

Answer (score 1):

Case of course is fine if you need to do it once. But if you do not want to update the Data itself and it just for reading or export use **IIF**. Here a small example:

```
declare @test table (
num nvarchar(10)
)

insert into @test
values ('9'),
       ('19'),
       ('15'),
       ('F'),
       ('UR'),
       ('B'),
       ('0'),
       ('00')

update @test
   set num = IIF(num like ('[0-9]'),'0' + num,num)

select *
  from @testenter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `TRY_CONVERT` to `NULL` the non integer values, and then use concatenation and `RIGHT` to add the leading zeroes:

```sql
SELECT ISNULL(RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(varchar(2),TRY_CONVERT(int,YourColumn)),2),YourColumn)
FROM dbo.YourTable;
```

Comment: Hi I am getting a syntax error on this code. I have this as `SELECT ISNULL(RIGHT(CONCAT('00',TRY_CONVERT(int,STOR_LEVEL_1)),2),STOR_LEVEL_1) AS NEW STOR_LEVEL_1`

Comment: *"I am getting a syntax error on this code."* And what is that error, the above works fine. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=264409757375ad1dc8f134b5d104c309)

Comment: @Nick `NEW STOR_LEVEL_1` is not a valid alias. Aliases and object names cannot contain spaces unless you delimit identify them.

Comment: Ok I have the query running, unfortunately this is making the non-numeric characters (i.e. 'F') be converted to '00'. I only want to pad numeric numbers that are single digit to be 2 digit (leading zero).

Comment: My bad, fixed, @Nick .